# Combine + SwiftUI Form + RunLoop causes table view to render unpredictably

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have a Combine function that I use to search through a list of items and return matches. It keeps track of not only what items to show the user that match the search term, but also what items have been marked as "chosen" by the user.

The function works great, including animations, until I add either `.debounce(for: .seconds(0.2), scheduler: RunLoop.main)` *or* `.receive(on: RunLoop.main)` in the Combine publisher chain. At that point, the rendering of the results in the `View` get inexplicably strange -- item titles start showing up as header views, items are repeated, etc.

You can see the result in the accompanying GIF.

[image]

The GIF version is using `.receive(on: RunLoop.main)`. Note I don't even use the search term here, although it *also* leads to funny results. It also may be worth noting that everything works correctly *with* the problem lines if `withAnimation { }` is removed.

I'd like to be able to use `debounce` as the list may eventually be pretty large and I don't want to filter the whole list on every keystroke.

**How can I get the table view to render correctly under these circumstances?**

Example code (see inline comments for the pain points and explanation of the code. It should run well as written, but if either of the two relevant lines is uncommented) :

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import UIKit

class Completer : ObservableObject {
    @Published var items : [Item] = [] {
        didSet {
            setupPipeline()
        }
    }
    @Published var filteredItems : [Item] = []
    @Published var chosenItems: Set<Item> = []
    @Published var searchTerm = ""
    
    private var filterCancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    private func setupPipeline() {
        filterCancellable =
            Publishers.CombineLatest($searchTerm,$chosenItems) //listen for changes of both the search term and chosen items
            .print()
            // ** Either of the following lines, if uncommented will cause chaotic rendering of the table **
            //.receive(on: RunLoop.main) //<----- HERE --------------------
            //.debounce(for: .seconds(0.2), scheduler: RunLoop.main) //<----- HERE --------------------
            .map { (term,chosen) -> (filtered: [Item],chosen: Set<Item>) in
                if term.isEmpty { //if the term is empty, return everything
                    return (filtered: self.items, chosen: chosen)
                } else { //if the term is not empty, return only items that contain the search term
                    return (filtered: self.items.filter { $0.name.localizedStandardContains(term) }, chosen: chosen)
                }
            }
            .map { (filtered,chosen) in
                (filtered: filtered.filter { !chosen.contains($0) }, chosen: chosen) //don't include any items in the chosen items list
            }
            .sink { [weak self] (filtered, chosen) in
                self?.filteredItems = filtered
            }
    }
    
    func toggleItemChosen(item: Item) {
        withAnimation {
            if chosenItems.contains(item) {
                chosenItems.remove(item)
            } else {
                searchTerm = ""
                chosenItems.insert(item)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var completer = Completer()
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Term", text: $completer.searchTerm)
            }
            Section {
                ForEach(completer.filteredItems) { item in
                    Button(action: {
                        completer.toggleItemChosen(item: item)
                    }) {
                        Text(item.name)
                    }.foregroundColor(completer.chosenItems.contains(item) ? .red : .primary)
                }
            }
            if completer.chosenItems.count != 0 {
                Section(header: HStack {
                    Text("Chosen items")
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        completer.chosenItems = []
                    }) {
                        Text("Clear")
                    }
                }) {
                    ForEach(Array(completer.chosenItems)) { item in
                        Button(action: {
                            completer.toggleItemChosen(item: item)
                        }) {
                            Text(item.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            completer.items = ["Chris", "Greg", "Ross", "Damian", "George", "Darrell", "Michael"]
                .map { Item(name: $0) }
        }
    }
}

struct Item : Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String
}
```

Comment: The `id` the `ForEach(Array(completer.chosenItems))` might be the problem

Comment: Something similar happened to me before because each item didn't have a unique ID - not sure but the `Array` might be erasing the `id` of your `Item`

Comment: Nope, sadly, that doesn't seem to be it. Changing `chosenItems` to `[Item]` and not a `Set` so I can use it directly in `ForEach` (including explicitly specifying the `id`) has no effect. Plus, as is, it still maintains its type (`Item`), which is `Identifiable` and has an `id` property, so nothing is "erased"

Comment: I don't have an answer but if you take out the "withAnimation" it seems to work with the .debounce included.

Comment: @nicksarno yes, I should probably add that to the question. Originally I found out about the issue because everything was working great and then I added `withAnimation` and it broke, which led me to narrow down the culprit to the `RunLoop` stuff

Comment: @jnpdx Interesting question. I'm investigating right now, and have found that if you have a `let _ = print(item.id)` just inside the bottom `ForEach` it prints twice - and the ids which have swapped orders are the ones which look "duplicated" in the displayed list. Might help for further investigating. (I also sort the set after it is converted to an array by the `name`). Maybe it's some weird issue where this `ForEach` updates twice when it should only do so once, very quickly, and causes this? Also... even after sorting this array, items still appear in a "random" order.

Comment: @George_E In my real code, I have sorting as well -- just removed it to get rid of as much code as possible for this example. Good idea with the `print` statements. I'm just confused why it can mess things up so badly that it even starts transposing the items and section headers

Comment: This may have uncovered a bug within SwiftUI. Without `receive(on:)`, the body is computed once: you update `chosenItems` and this synchronously emits a value in the pipeline and updates `filteredItems` (actually, it wastefully happens twice on insert, because of `searchTerm = ""`). But when you use `receive(on:)` the ordering is different, and it causes the body to be computed twice.

Comment: @NewDev yes, my suspicion is that it'll join my growing queue of SwiftUI-related feedbacks... Regarding the wasteful update when `searchTerm = ""`, I tried rewriting everything without @Published values and just triggering `objectWillChange` to avoid the extra update, but I managed to lose the fancy table insert/delete animations in the process.

Comment: Is this just an intellectual exercise? I mean, it works without `receive(on:)`, so what are you looking for in an answer? Why do you need `receive(on:)` or `debounce` here?

Comment: @New Dev — no, it’s not just an exercise (not a fan of those on SO in general, personally). The main point is to get debounce working as I describe in the question, when working with very large data sets. Receive(on:) just happened to be something that I ran across while trying to debug it that happened to have the same resultant characteristics (the RunLoop being the common factor). Happy to accept an answer that allows me to debounce and keep the animation. My suspicion is that I’ll end up having to ditch the animation in the app so that I can get the debounce behavior correct.

Comment: Or, I suppose I could try writing it with a UITableView and diffable data source.

Comment: What are you debouncing? Debounce swallows (drops) values - that doesn't feel like something you'd need here? Perhaps you're trying to debounce `searchTerm` changes? If so, then you should do `$searchTerm.debounce(...).removeDuplicates().combineLatest($choosenItems)` or would that also fail?

Comment: @NewDev that is correct -- it's the `searchTerm` I want to debounce. I tried your strategy just now. It works great for just updating `chosenItems`, but as soon as the search field is used, screwy behavior shows up again and the table headers get mixed up, etc. A step in the right direction, but not a fix, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Asperi's suggestion got me on the right track thinking about how many `withAnimation { }` events would get called. In my original question, `filteredItems` and `chosenItems` would be changed in different iterations of the RunLoop when `receive(on:)` or `debounce` was used, which seemed to be the root cause of the unpredictable layout behavior.

By changing the `debounce` time to a longer value, this would prevent the issue, because one animation would be done *after* the other was finished, but was a problematic solution because it relied on the animation times (and potentially magic numbers if explicit animation times weren't sent).

I've engineered a somewhat tacky solution that uses a `PassThroughSubject` for `chosenItems` instead of assigning to the `@Published` property directly. By doing this, I can move all assignment of the `@Published` values into the `sink`, resulting in just *one* animation block happening.

I'm not thrilled with the solution, as it feels like an unnecessary hack, but it does seem to solve the issue:

```
class Completer : ObservableObject {
    @Published var items : [Item] = [] {
        didSet {
            setupPipeline()
        }
    }
    @Published private(set) var filteredItems : [Item] = []
    @Published private(set) var chosenItems: Set<Item> = []
    @Published var searchTerm = ""
    
    private var chosenPassthrough : PassthroughSubject<Set<Item>,Never> = .init()
    private var filterCancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    private func setupPipeline() {
        filterCancellable =
            Publishers.CombineLatest($searchTerm,chosenPassthrough)
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.2), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .map { (term,chosen) -> (filtered: [Item],chosen: Set<Item>) in
                if term.isEmpty {
                    return (filtered: self.items, chosen: chosen)
                } else {
                    return (filtered: self.items.filter { $0.name.localizedStandardContains(term) }, chosen: chosen)
                }
            }
            .map { (filtered,chosen) in
                (filtered: filtered.filter { !chosen.contains($0) }, chosen: chosen)
            }
            .sink { [weak self] (filtered, chosen) in
                withAnimation {
                    self?.filteredItems = filtered
                    self?.chosenItems = chosen
                }
            }
        chosenPassthrough.send([])
    }
    
    func toggleItemChosen(item: Item) {
        if chosenItems.contains(item) {
            var copy = chosenItems
            copy.remove(item)
            chosenPassthrough.send(copy)
        } else {
            var copy = chosenItems
            copy.insert(item)
            chosenPassthrough.send(copy)
        }
        searchTerm = ""
    }
    
    func clearChosen() {
        chosenPassthrough.send([])
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var completer = Completer()
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Term", text: $completer.searchTerm)
            }
            Section {
                ForEach(completer.filteredItems) { item in
                    Button(action: {
                        completer.toggleItemChosen(item: item)
                    }) {
                        Text(item.name)
                    }.foregroundColor(completer.chosenItems.contains(item) ? .red : .primary)
                }
            }
            if completer.chosenItems.count != 0 {
                Section(header: HStack {
                    Text("Chosen items")
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        completer.clearChosen()
                    }) {
                        Text("Clear")
                    }
                }) {
                    ForEach(Array(completer.chosenItems)) { item in
                        Button(action: {
                            completer.toggleItemChosen(item: item)
                        }) {
                            Text(item.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            completer.items = ["Chris", "Greg", "Ross", "Damian", "George", "Darrell", "Michael"]
                .map { Item(name: $0) }
        }
    }
}

struct Item : Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in handling async processing... In your default case all operations are performed synchronously **within one(!)** animation block, so all works fine. But in second scenario (by introducing any scheduler in publishers chain) some operations are performed synchronously (like removing) that initiates animation, but operation from publisher comes asynchronously at the moment when animation is already in progress, and changing model breaks that running animation giving unpredictable result.

The possible approach to solve this is to separate initiating and resulting operations by different blocks and make publishers chan really async but processing in background and retrieving results in main queue.

Here is modified publishers chain. Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

*Note: also you can investigate possibility of wrapping all again in one animation block, but already in `synk` after retrieving results - this will require changing logic so it just for consideration*

[image]

```
private func setupPipeline() {
    filterCancellable =
        Publishers.CombineLatest($searchTerm,$chosenItems)
        .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)   // debounce input
        .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))         // prepare for processing in background
        .print()
        .map { (term,chosen) -> (filtered: [DItem],chosen: Set<DItem>) in
            if term.isEmpty { //if the term is empty, return everything
                return (filtered: self.items, chosen: chosen)
            } else { //if the term is not empty, return only items that contain the search term
                return (filtered: self.items.filter { $0.name.localizedStandardContains(term) }, chosen: chosen)
            }
        }
        .map { (filtered,chosen) in
            (filtered: filtered.filter { !chosen.contains($0) }, chosen: chosen) //don't include any items in the chosen items list
        }
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main) // << receive processed items on main queue
        .sink { [weak self] (filtered, chosen) in
            withAnimation {
                self?.filteredItems = filtered      // animating this as well
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting -- I'll likely be using this as it did lead to a workable solution, *but*, while testing I discovered that for me, your code seemed to work exactly the same as mine if I changed the debounce time back to 0.2 instead of 0.5 -- none of the other `subscribe`, `DispatchQueue`, `withAnimation` seem to matter, in fact -- it's merely the fact that the debounce window is longer (and thus probably after the initial animation finishes). Can you confirm that the same happens when you try it with 0.2?