# SwiftUI View reads stale ObservableObject property value

Tags: swiftui

I am seeing a very strange state behavior when updating ObservableObjects on iOS 14.5 under a very particular condition. I suspect this is a SwiftUI bug - I extracted code to reproduce this from my application for further investigation.

The question is: Is this actually a bug in SwiftUI or is there an explanation for the behavior?

The bug is hard to reproduce, so let's start simple: Assume we have two models FlipModel (storing a value `flipped`) and `CounterModel` (keeping the number the value has been flipped). The flipped value is observed via `onReceive` and if a value change occurs, the counter is incremented. **This is just an arbitrary, simplified example to be able to reproduce the bug.**

```swift
class FlipModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var flipped = true {
        didSet {
            print("new value for flipped: \(self.flipped)")
        }
    }
}

class CounterModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counter = 0
}

struct StrangeStateGlitchExampleView: View {

    @StateObject var flipModel = FlipModel()
    @StateObject var counterModel = CounterModel()

    // MARK: - View

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Button("Toggle value from SwiftUI") {
                self.flipModel.flipped.toggle()
            }
            Text("Flipped: \(String(describing: flipModel.flipped))")
            Text("Flipped \(self.counterModel.counter) times")
        }
        .onReceive(self.flipModel.$flipped, perform: { _ in
            withAnimation {
                self.counterModel.counter += 1
            }
        })
    }

}

struct StrangeStateGlitchExampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        StrangeStateGlitchExampleView()
    }
}
```

This works fine:

[image: state issue]

Now let's add three things to the example that are all necessary for the bug to occur:

1. The change is not done from SwiftUI, but from a background thread via `DispatchQueue.main.async`.
2. FlipModel is also observed from another view.
3. The counter change is done in an `withAnimation` block.

Example code:

```swift
class FlipModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var flipped = true {
        didSet {
            print("new value for flipped: \(self.flipped)")
        }
    }
}

class CounterModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counter = 0
}

struct StrangeStateGlitchExampleView: View {

    @StateObject var flipModel = FlipModel()
    @StateObject var counterModel = CounterModel()

    // MARK: - View

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Button("Toggle value from SwiftUI") {
                self.flipModel.flipped.toggle()
            }
            Button("Toggle value from external thread") {
                // --> 1) The change is not done from SwiftUI.
                // but from a background thread via `DispatchQueue.main.async`.
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.flipModel.flipped.toggle()
                }
            }
            // -- 2) FlipModel is also observed from another view.
            OtherView(flipModel: self.flipModel)
            Text("Flipped (ExampleView): \(String(describing: flipModel.flipped))")
            Text("Flipped \(self.counterModel.counter) times")
        }
        .onReceive(self.flipModel.$flipped, perform: { _ in
            // --> 3) The counter change is done in an `withAnimation` block.
            withAnimation {
                self.counterModel.counter += 1
            }
        })
    }

}

struct OtherView: View {

    @ObservedObject var flipModel: FlipModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("Flipped (OtherView): \(String(describing: flipModel.flipped))")
    }
}

struct StrangeStateGlitchExampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        StrangeStateGlitchExampleView()
    }
}
```

Now, if the change is triggered like that, the `OtherView` reads an old value for `flipped`:

[image]

Comment: Both models seem to be pointless if nothing happens to be published inside them. With your code you can realize the same functionality just with `@State` properties and `@Bindings`

Comment: Yes, as mentioned: this is just an arbitrary example to be able to reproduce the behavior. The actual models are more complex and make sense. I know how to work around this. But I think it pinpoints a SwiftUI issue.

Comment: @RalfEbert This issues sounds similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67133680/9607863) question... have a read through that, may be some useful information there. This might be a separate issue, but it sounds familiar where using a different thread with `withAnimation` which causes update problems.